# Returning a struct with a function member that refer to a variable in parent scope

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a function that returns a struct with a member function that refer to a variable in parent scope.

```
struct Scanner {
  int nextToken();
}

Scanner test() {
  token = 1;
  return {
    int nextToken() {
      return token;
    }
  };
}
```

I don't know if this is doable in `C++`.  I'm a JavaScript developer and I don't know how to accomplish this. Are there any suggestion on how to refer to the variable `token` and return a struct or class that can provide a function `nextToken()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in older versions of the C++ standard (at least not as easy).

The far better (and easier) approach would be using C++11's lambdas.

Something like this (untested right now and most likely includes some syntax problem or other mistake somewhere):

```
struct Scanner {
    std::function<int()> nextToken;
};

Scanner test() {
    token = 1;
    return {
        [=](){ return token; }
    };
}
```

However, are you really sure you'll need to do it this way? This seems like a perfect use case for simple/classic class inheritance (which is possible with structs as well):

```
struct Scanner {
    virtual int nextToken() { return 0; }
}

struct TestScanner : public Scanner {
    virtual int nextToken() { return 1; }
}
```

Comment: It should read `std::function<int()> nextToken;` (change is too small to make an edit). But yeah, use inheritance. In that case if you're using C++11 (you should, it's been 4 years :) ), I'd write the method in TestScanner as `int nextToken() override { return 1; }`.

Comment: I'm not sure if he need a lambda (probably not), but that's most natural thing to do in javascript...